# Halving Points in Yu-Gi-Oh!

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What happens if points (Life Points, Attack Points or Life Points) should be halved, but are a odd number?

Some cards like Solemn Judgement can half a variable, while some monsters like S39 Utopia Prime have weird stats that can generate odd stats by halving.

I tried to find out the answer and I found this talk: https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Forum:25_Life_Points_divided_by_2%3F

But I did not find some serious source. Is it halved up to the next integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Not only LP, but all values in Yu-Gi-Oh are rounded up after being halved while odd.

Unfortunately, official sources verifying this are either nonexistent or are very difficult to find; however, this is something that can easily be verified by halving ATK, LP, etc repeatedly in any officially licensed Yu-Gi-Oh game - such as Duel Links or Legacy of the Duelist.

If I find any direct footage of this occuring, I'll add it to this answer right away.

**EDIT:** So, I wasn't able to find footage, but I was able to find this:
https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Solemn_Judgment

In the card rulings for Solemn Judgement, under "Previously Official Rulings", we have:

> If halving your Life Points results in a fraction, your Life Points are rounded up.

Now, of course, this is a *previously* official ruling, but unless there is a ruling that directly states to the contrary, this ruling can/should still be considered correct. This also technically is a ruling for Solemn Judgement specifically, but I think in this case it's a safe assumption that the idea is extensible.

Comment: Huh, my research also hasn't found any "official" (or official-ish) source that is backed up by anything...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I actually just found something and edited it into my answer, but it's definitely strange how much digging this took... you'd really think there would be more word on this, given how many cards halve values.

Comment: It is unavoidably contradictory to say that "all values" are rounded up.  If you take damage and round up the resulting life points, you are simultaneously ***rounding down the damage.***  You could just as easily view this as removing half your life points rounded down (which actually makes more sense to me personally).

Comment: Well yes, I suppose it would be contradictory if I only said that all values are rounded up. I said that all values are rounded up when halved while odd, which is not a contradiction at all. I suppose you could view it in the way that you mention, but this seems like an inconsequential semantic way of expressing the concept, not a contradiction.